# Keycloak Error with Docker and Letsencrypt certificates

Tags: docker, ssl, keycloak

I use the standard Docker image from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Then I run the following command to build it:

```
docker run \
 -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/fullchain.pem \
 -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/privatekey.pem:/etc/x509/https/privatekey.pem \
 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=myadmin \
 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=mypassword \
 -p 8443:8443 jboss/keycloak
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-1) Closing SSLConduit after
>   exception on handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher
>   suites in common

Do I have to convert the files to `.crt` and `.key?` I thought it would not matter. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what is source of that error and used Keycloak version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Keycloak is not using your provided Private-Key and Certificates. They should be provided as `tls.key` and `tls.crt`
So changing your mounts accordingly should be enough:

```
-v /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt \
-v /etc/letsencrypt/live/ds-gym.de/privatekey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key \
```

My keycloak instance is also running with the latest keycloak version and LetsEncrypt without any problems

**Edit:**

My docker-compose setup, maybe it helps you debugging.

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121  904 Dez 22 13:28 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 3566 Dez 22 13:28 fullchain.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 1708 Dez 22 13:28 privatekey.pem
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
       - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
       - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    ports:
       - 8443:8443
    environment:
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      JDBC_PARAMS: "useSSL=false"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/opt/jboss/mysql_data
      - ./fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - ./privatekey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
```

After keycloak is started, I can connect to it via SSL

```
$ curl -v 'https://localhost:8443'
0* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
...
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=mydomain.com
*        start date: 2019-10-29 01:25:18 GMT
*        expire date: 2020-01-27 01:25:18 GMT
*        subjectAltName does not match localhost
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'
* Closing connection 0
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [2 bytes data]
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'
```

SSL overall is working, it just fails because the LetsEnctypt-certificate is not valid for localhost :-)

Comment: @DataMastery - you can't change path in the container, unless you made more advanced configuration

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately stil getting that error :-(. What you do exactly mean with that Jan Garaj? Where is my path wrong?

Comment: @DataMastery Keycloak is configured by default to use `/etc/x509/https/tls.crt` container path for TLS cert, but you are placing own cert in different path `/etc/x509/https/fullchain.pem`. So of course default cert is still picked up in this case. You can use use own path `/etc/x509/https/fullchain.pem`,  but you need to configure Keycloak to use new custom path somehow.

Comment: ah ok I understand :-). Does it matter if the original certicate has got a .pem ending? Is there a need for converting it?

Comment: No normally you don't need to convert it

Comment: OK thank you. Would you Kindly provide me the code for your working instance?

Comment: I have another idea why it might not work: Does that tls.crt and tls.key have to match in the nginx configuration?

Comment: @DataMastery - see my edited answer, I added my docker-compose stack and hopefully it's helpful for debugging. I don't know exactly how the nginx is used in your setup, but keep in mind: In your (and mine) configuration, SSL is terminated at keycloak, so the whole SSL connection need to reach keycloak (a possible nginx instance is in this case can only act as a proxy and should not touch the ssl at all)